# Power BI summation of negative values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get grand totals at the bottom of Category 1 in PowerBI, so far I have been unsuccessful. Can someone point the error out

[image]

```
Category 1 = If(%Salary/Desired Salary < .90, Difference, 0)
```

It does not give me a total of -30,000. I would want to know what the total difference is going to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use **calculated columns**

```
Category 1 = 
IF(
    'Table'[% Salery / Desired Salary] < .9, 
    'Table'[Difference], 
    0
)
```

[image]